# Setting up davmail on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am trying to set it up on Amazon EC2 so that I can convert an OWA email into an IMAP email that I can access from anywhere. I tried setting up the server using the davmail.properties file that is here: http://davmail.sourceforge.net/serversetup.html and trying to follow these instructions: https://nmarlier.wordpress.com/2015/08/28/davmail-on-ec2-with-smtp-on-465/. My server seems to be running without any problems, but I cannot get Thunderbird on my local machine to connect. I have tried all different options for the account setup. I have tried working with the AWS secutiry groups and the local firewall, but I am not sure what needs to be done.

Comment: The local Thunderbird says it cannot connect to the server

Comment: can you connect to the instance:port via telnet or else?